# TiddlyWiki: How does TiddlyWiki save its changes to itself on the local file system?

Tags: javascript, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

How does TiddlyWiki save its changes to itself on the local file system?
And how does TiddlyWiki keep the each tiddler's change until "Save Changes" is executed?

I want to understand the mechanisms.
But I cannot figure it out from the source code.

Could you help insufficient-knowledge-of-JavaScript people like me?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

In general? Poorly. [The TiddlyWiki web site has details](http://tiddlywiki.com/#GettingStarted), but in brief:

- TiddlyWiki allows a wiki to be saved by generating a new HTML file in Javascript which represents the saved contents of the wiki, and presenting this to the user as a download. The user must explicitly replace the old file with the new downloaded copy for this to work properly.
- The [TiddlyFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tiddlyfox/) extension for Firefox explicitly allows a TiddlyWiki HTML file to overwrite itself. Maybe. (The comments on the extension suggest this may not even work properly anymore.)

Comment: Thank you for quick response!

Comment: This helps me understand.  If possible, could you point the part of the source code of TiddlyWiki5 which call the saving-changes-and-prompting-users-to-download function?